# Is it possible to use symfony debug bar standalone?

Tags: symfony, debugging

I am trying to use the Symfony debug bar in a standalone application without symfony framework. I have install the package using composer but whe i run Debug::enable() no bar shows up in the screen. Am i missing anything?

thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Symfony debug toolbar is coming from the [SymfonyWebProfilerBundle](https://github.com/symfony/web-profiler-bundle) and not directly included in the Debug component.

Also, because it's a bundle, you surely have to make some changes if you want use it as a standalone component (out of symfony).

Maybe look at the [Laravel debug toolbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) which is not a Symfony2 Bundle and can be easier to a adapt. It is built from the following package.

**EDIT**

The laravel toolbar is directly coming from [maximebf/php-debugbar](https://github.com/maximebf/php-debugbar) which can be easily integrated in your PHP project.

Comment: See my edit, you can integrate the last package in php project